# Почему цикл не обрывается?

Tags: python

Когда комбинация становиться [1,2,3] , почему цикл не прерывается?

Код:

```
import random


class Listing:

    def __init__(self, lis, first_num, last_num):

        self.lis = lis
        self.last_num = last_num
        self.first_num = first_num

    def run(self):
        while True:
            lis = [i for i in range(self.first_num, self.last_num + 1)]
            random.shuffle(lis)
            print(lis)

            lis = [self.first_num, self.last_num]

            if lis == [range(self.first_num, self.last_num)]:
                break
            else:
                continue


list_1 = Listing([], 1, 3)
list_1.run()
```

Comment: Потому что условие `[self.first_num, self.last_num] == [range(self.first_num, self.last_num)]` никогда не выполняется. Слева список из двух элементов (двух чисел), справа список из одного элемента (объекта типа range). Списки разной длины и с разным содержимым, значит они не равны.

Comment: Ну и еще к размышлению: `list(range(X, Y)) != [range(X, Y)]` (по тем же причинам по сути: слева список чисел, справа список из одного объекта типа range).

Comment: range всегда новый - вот и не работает

Answer (score 0):

Потому что твое условие `lis == [range(self.first_num, self.last_num)]` никогда не выполняется.
Когда комбинация становиться [1,2,3] , почему цикл не прерывается?
в lis у тебя [1,2,3] потом допустим [1,2], тогда как `[range(self.first_num, self.last_num)]` у тебя = `[range(1,3)]`, вероятнее всего тебе надо сделать так `[x for x in range(self.first_num, self.last_num) + 1]` но к чему лишние вычисления если можно сделать так:

```
import random


class Listing:

    def __init__(self, lis, first_num, last_num):
        self.lis = lis
        self.last_num = last_num
        self.first_num = first_num

    def run(self):
        a = [1,3]
        while True:
            lis = [i for i in range(self.first_num, self.last_num + 1)]
            random.shuffle(lis)
            lis = [self.first_num, self.last_num]
            if lis == a:
                print("Остановка цикла")
                break
            else:
                continue


list_1 = Listing([], 1, 3)
list_1.run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем тебе тут range?